# How to use JS libraries in Google Sheet App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to write a custom function in Google Sheet to generate barcodes. How do I import external js libraries (e.g. https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/)?

This is what have I so far:

```
function genBarcode(input) {
  var url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js";
  var js = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  eval(js);
  // I want to do something like this
  // return JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi world!");
  // But Google sheet says JsBarcode is undefine. 
}
```

Comment: Given the rather significant difference between modern JavaScript and Google Apps Script, odds are you will not be able to simply evaluate or import a generic library unless it is compatible with JavaScript 1.6. Consider porting the library, and importing your port as a standard Google Apps Script library.

Comment: You rewrite the library into app script?

Comment: Search for transpilers....