# Is there a way to scrape Javascript content with Google Script?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, web-scraping, puppeteer, dynamic-content

I want to make a script on Google Script that would take me the information from this page: https://www.pinnacle.com/fr/

The problem is that this information is only displayed after a waiting time labs via a Javascript script.

I'm familiar with the Selenium (for python) and Puppeteer (for NodeJS) libraries, but I don't know how to import libraries into Google Script, and Google Script doesn't work with python (at least it seems to me).

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use an external javascript library in a Google Apps addon script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766876/how-do-you-use-an-external-javascript-library-in-a-google-apps-addon-script)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52528295/1595451 (no answer yet)

Comment: No because Puppeteer library are not sum up into a unique file, it's a folder with a lot of document :'(